# NRZ Encoding Scheme

Tags: ethernet, layer2

Could someone explain why having a long sequence of 0s or 1s is bad if we use NRZ Encoding? Is it because if we were to have two signals (i.e. 00011000 and 01111111), then with NRZ encoding we couldn't tell where the 1st signal ends and the second signal begins?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nrz requires an external clock to keep in sync. Otherwise long sequences of the same digit may get out of sync, and a string of twenty zeros might be mistaken for nineteen zeros, for example.